# CSS animation bounce (with a curve)

Tags: html, css, animation, bounce

I'm trying to make a bouncing ball with a CSS animation.

```
.bouncing-ball{-webkit-animation:bounce 3s;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce{50% {bottom:20%;left:40%;}100% {left:80%;bottom:0;}}
```

When I use this code I get the animation like show on [this picture](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-p57FJ21FlvQ/VCV8fV30xFI/AAAAAAAABPQ/9C-n1tJStxI/w727-h275-no/Artboard%2B1.png) (The red one). How do I get an animation like the green one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify two simultaneous animations, one that moves the ball up and down and another that moves it from left to right:

```
.bouncing-ball {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;

    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    animation: bounce 3s, move 3s; // separated by a comma

}

@keyframes bounce{
    100% {
        left:80%;
    }
}

@keyframes move {
    50% {
        bottom: 20%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0b48ehvd/1/) to see it in action.